# POST http://localhost:3000/undefined/post 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm tried to fatch my api data from backend by using axios. I'm getting an error, like this:

`POST http://localhost:3000/undefined/post 404 (Not Found)`

API routes like this:

```
// route middleware
app.use("/api", portRoutes);

// passing on controllers
router.post("/post", create);

// rest of code will have in controller folder
```

Now I have tried to work in frontend

I have tried by this way:

`.env` file

`REACT_APP_API = http://localhost:8000/api`

I dont know why does not access my server side links

`handleSubmit` function

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // access data from backend
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/post`, { title, content, user })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setState({ ...state, title: "", content: "", user: "" });
        alert(`Post Title ${response.data.title} is created`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
        alert(error.response.data.error);
      });
  };
```

I'm sure my api is ok, I have checked my api with postman software.

Comment: If you are sending a query to `http://localhost:3000/undefined/post` that means that `process.env.REACT_APP_API` is undefined

Comment: I don't know why show me `undefined` it should be `api`

Comment: Your code is running in a browser, `process.env.REACT_APP_API` is from node.js which is on the server side. You can't access server side env vars from client side js directly.

Comment: if you are working with webpack and it's processing `process.env` for you, ensure you have the correct configuration in your `package.json` being set.

Comment: also if you are working with `create-react-app`, ensure you have `react-scripts` >`0.2.3` and proper `react-scripts` commands for your `npm start` script

Comment: @lastr2d2 right now I'm using `"react-scripts": "4.0.1",` this version

Comment: @Sheikh then there are a few debugging tips https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237511/553073

Comment: @lastr2d2 Thanks man, you save my time by send this link.

Comment: Actually, I forgot re-start my client server + my backend server was stop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229431/discussion-between-sheikh-and-lastr2d2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my error from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined/53237511#53237511)
Please feel free read this article if you faced same problem, that I have faced.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe add some detail other than a link and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cant access .env file from server side in your frontend app.

My suggestion is create in your frontend a config axios file

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
});

export default api;
```

Then in your `handleSubmit` function:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // access data from backend
    api
      .post(`/post`, { title, content, user })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setState({ ...state, title: "", content: "", user: "" });
        alert(`Post Title ${response.data.title} is created`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
        alert(error.response.data.error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: it can be done with a `create-react-app` which OP could use. the `process.env.REACT_APP_X` will be replaced during the build, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

this is also due to .env file in src folder... move it outside of src folder to the main client folder