# Cannot Connect to Firestore Database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When trying to get a document and its fields from Firestore I get the following errors:

From Local Host:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.3.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project "xxxxxxxxx".
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

From Firebase Hosting:

```
BrowserPollConnection.ts:728 GET https://[PROJECT_ID]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=82934841&cb=1&v=5&p=1:303920306737:web:bc61250d7aa9a51a415310 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

When looking up this issue the resolution seems to be caching, DNS, ISP, VPN, or something of the likes. I have tried every proposed solution and still no resolution. I'm thinking it might be how I configured the connection?

The only thing I find odd is that it states its trying to go to **https://[PROJECT_ID]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com** which I thought is only for RTDB but I am using Firestore.

In my configuration file I have the following:

**firebase/index.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

var config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: `${process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseapp.com`,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE,
  messagingSenderId:process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId:process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
  
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase;
```

I'm trying to just get one document in a `useEffect`. Weird thing is that once it returns `setData`, doing data.id prints out the actual ID however within the `useEffect` or out of it checking if the doc exists `docSnapshot.exists` is always false. Probably because of my connection issues.

```
import firebase from './firebase';
const db = firebase.firestore();
.
.
.

    useEffect(() => {
           
    
    
            db.collection('myCollection').doc('myDocID')
            .onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
    
                console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
                setData(docSnapshot);
    
            }, err => {
                console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    
            });
    },[]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was actually in my `.env` file where I had quotes `"` around the variables. This caused them to be undefined and thus couldn't connect. This question answer helped me

[react evironment variables .env return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined/53237511)

Comment: Had the same issue. Removing the `"`  surrounding the environment variables solved the problem for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `code=permission-denied`. So I think you should try to generate a new API key to check if the errors is caused by permission or your missed configuration