# .env returning data unfeind in react

Tags: reactjs

.env

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

react file

```
    export const signupfetch=user=>{
    
    return fetch(`process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`,{
       method:"POST",
       
       headers:{
           Accept:"application/json",
           "Content-Type":"application/json"
       },
       body:JSON.stringify(user)
   }).then(response=>{return response.json()})
   .catch(err=>console.log(err))
};
enter code here
```

REACT_APP_API_UR is returning data undefind for all the urls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react evironment variables .env return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem happened because you converted `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` into a string and are trying to fetch it.

You shouldn't use the grave accent, or any apostrophe, around it. So simply remove the `` and try running like this:

```
return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,{
       method:"POST",
```