# Environment variables are not working in React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, environment-variables

I'm currently working with a 3rd party API, which has an API key. I am intending to store it in a `.env` file and have been doing it but it always comes up as `undefined` when I try to access it with `process.env`.

My `.env` file is `keys.env` which is outside of the `src` directory of my `React JS` app. I have restarted my development server, cleaned the cache of `npm` but my `React JS` app does not recognize the `.env` variable at all.

My File Structure:

```
|-node_modules<br>
|-public<br>
|-src<br>
|  .gitignore<br>
|  keys.env<br>
|  package-lock.json<br>
|  package.json <br>
```

My `keys.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_TEST_KEY=somekey
```

How the `.env` variable is accessed:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_KEY
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react evironment variables .env return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined)

Comment: Yes, tried almost everything here.

Comment: Did you restart server after changing `.env` file? Also `keys.env` is not a valid environment file. Please check [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used). Any reason why you are using `keys.env` instead if  `.env` file?

Comment: I tried restarting few times, and also cleared the cache. I did not try expanding the env variables as mentioned in this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need config **webpack** file to use keys.env because the file name default of environment is **.env**

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
 
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
        path: './some.other.env' // default is .env
    })
  ]
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks!. I did not follow this, instead I renamed my file to just `.env` instead of `keys.env` to get rid of the extra setup. However, according to the previous approach, this is the way to go.