# Set Graphql URI in React with .env

Tags: reactjs, graphql, environment-variables

I'm trying to develop using localhost on one machine (via `localhost:5000/graphql`) and using Github codespaces on another (via `https://githubuser-repo-wackycode-5000.githubpreview.dev/graphql`).

In my `index.tsx` I have:

```
const graphqlHost: string = (process.env.GRAPHQL_HOST as string);

console.log(graphqlHost);

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: graphqlHost,
  credentials: 'same-origin'

});
```

My .env (located just outside of `/src` looks as follows:

```
# GRAPHQL_HOST="localhost:5000/graphql"
GRAPHQL_HOST="https://githubuser-repo-wackycode-5000.githubpreview.dev/graphql"
```

[image]

Error I'm getting (obviously not resolving .env):
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'graphql'`

Everything does would when the `uri` is hardcoded.

What's the proper .env setup I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try something like this? The **.env** files doesn't need quotes.

```
GRAPHQL_HOST=https://githubuser-repo-wackycode-5000.githubpreview.dev/graphql
```

If that doesn't work try to create a dummy key and check if you can get it.

**.env**

```
DUMMY=dummy
```

**index.tsx**

```
const graphqlHost: string = (process.env.DUMMY as string);
```

Comment: I'm getting `graphqlHost: undefined` when piping to console. I'm thinking *smh* that this is b/c I'm developing on a Github Codespace. They have whole section just for .env variables. Testing now.

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237511/664933) I had to use prefixed with `REACT_APP_`. Now `REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_HOST` is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined) I had to use the prefixed `REACT_APP_`.

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_HOST=https://githubuser-repo-wackycode-5000.githubpreview.dev/graphql
```

**index.tsx**

```
const graphqlHost: string = (process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_HOST as string);

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: graphqlHost,
  credentials: 'same-origin'

});
```

Also as [recommended by Github](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-codespaces) I added the .env variable to my Codespace... therefore I can spin up another instance without worrying about updating my .env on the Codespace.