# How to access env variables using react?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

This might be a repeat, but I can't find an answer for my particular use case. I have a react app created using `npx create-react-app app` and a .env file in my root directory. Appending "REACT_APP" to my variables don't register under `process.env`, with the only variables being registered are `FAST_REFRESH: true`, `NODE_ENV: "development"`, `PUBLIC_URL: ""`, `WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined`, `WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined`, and `WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined`. How do I access the environment variables in my .env file?

Here are my vars:

```
REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID="service"
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID="template"
REACT_APP_VAR="show"
```

Comment: Have you installed the dotenv package?

Comment: See this [react evironment variables .env return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react evironment variables .env return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem: Only the predefined env variables were printed, my custom variables – although prefixed with REACT_APP were printed as undefined in dev mode when I tried to get them with process.env.REACT_APP_MYVAR.

Stopping the local host and starting the app once again with 'npm start' fixed the issue.

Comment: That was my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here are the docs for adding custom environment variables: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/.

It should be as simple as `process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID`.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need explicit define that my variable is string or number etc `.env` do it himself first you can access it using

```
process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID
```

or a better way is to create a `config.js` file and inside you export all the `.env` variables like this

```
export default {
  SERVIVE_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
  TEMPLATE_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,
  VAR: process.env.REACT_APP_VAR
};
```

after that import, it and you are good to go.