# Variable in ENV file undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access a variable in my .env file. Unfortunately, I am getting an undefined back.

**.env** file

```
REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL = ws://localhost:2900
```

attempt to access it

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL); //undefined
},[]);
```

Comment: Please check duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react evironment variables .env return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined)

Comment: no duplicate. I use the prefix REACT_APP

Comment: @SumitSingh That's the same question linked above by sedhal.

Comment: I created the app using create-react-app. that's why I don't need dotenv

Comment: Having environment variables available in `process.env` at runtime is a feature of `create-react-app`. As in, there needs to be build-time script that copies the env vars from the nodejs shell env into the frontend build. This also means there needs to be a script that uses the dotenv nodejs dependency.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of `create-react-app`, using `.env` hasn't always been supported https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables
2. Make sure `.env` is located in the project root where `package.json` is.
3. Try not having spaces in `.env`, try putting the value in double quotes (`"ws://localhost:2900"`)
4. Restart the dev server, changes to `.env` aren't picked up automatically as it works for hot module reloading