# Env variables are undefined on frontend with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I'm trying to move all the sensitive variables to .env file. It works just fine server side on Node but I'm having trouble doing it with React.

I referenced these answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237511/13941802) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945430/13941802)

1.I changed my .env so it looks like this

```
REACT_APP_SIGNER_PK = xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx
```

Added the variable itself to the file containing script

```
const REACT_APP_SIGNER_PK = process.env.REACT_APP_SIGNER_PK;
```

2. Placed .env inside of my **root** folder
3. I restart the server after the changes with `yarn run dev`

To test out the changes I put this print statement from the file where I put the env variable in

```
console.log(REACT_APP_SIGNER_PK);
```

On the restart of the local server I check the console and in the terminal where the server is running I see the print statement with my environmental variable, but in the browser console I see this print as `undefined`

The only thing that differs in my action from the references is that I use `yarn run` other than `npm start`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using CRA?

Comment: yes, with nextJS on top

Comment: Next is different to CRA https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: Solved the issue, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from @OFRBG I managed to find a solution.

Adding `REACT_APP_` app to the my .env variables did not work because I was using nextJS instead of Create-React-App.

In order to fix the problem this problem **for nextJS users** add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` instead as a prefix for your .env variables