# REACT_APP_ variable returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I am going mad with my react app's env variable that always returns "undefined".

I have created a file called ".env" in my root folder, hence where all the other react components are found, including app.jsx that uses the variable.

Within the .env file, I have created a Mapbox token like this

REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN=pk.eyXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX (exactly that name and my personal token, without quote or anything)

I am then trying to assign the variable to my constant in my app:

```
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN;
```

which I then use for a deck.gl map

```
return (
    <>
      <Map
        initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
        mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
        mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      >
        <DeckGLOverlay layers={[cpuGridLayer]} />
        <NavigationControl position='top-left' />
    </>
  );
}
```

No matter what I do, it always returns undefined. If I place my token directly into app.jsx, everything works perfectly. As per my understanding, my implementation fulfils all requirements (root folder, correct naming etc.)

Of course I have also restarted my react server several times.

I am working on a Mac.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237293/react-evironment-variables-env-return-undefined
1. Check if you added trailing commas in your env.
2. How did you create the project? For example with create-react-app?
If not, install dotenv package

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have tried this, also without success unfortunately.